# Flexible column widths in table with scrollable body

Tags: css

I currently have following implementatin where I want the body of the table to be scrollable. However, the column widths are all of equal width and I am trying to figure out how to achieve a  flexible tablecell width based on content, while keeping the body's scrolling. ideas?

```css
.modal {
  height: 300px;
}

.first {
  height: 100%;
}

table.list {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

thead,
tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 40px;
}

th {
  padding: 0 $now-global-space--sm 0 $now-global-space--md;
  text-align: left;
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

tbody {
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

tr {
  line-height: 1.5;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: none;
  min-height: 40px;
}

td {
  min-height: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background-color: red;
}

tr:hover td {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="first">
    <table class="list" role="grid">
      <thead>
        <tr role="row">
          <th role="columnheader">Date</th>
          <th role="columnheader">Action</th>
          <th role="columnheader">Comment</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 24</td>
          <td role="gridcell">somoene</td>
          <td role="gridcell">ddddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 23</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">ddddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 22</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">dd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 21</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">asd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 20</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadasdsa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 14</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsadsadsa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 7</td>
          <td role="gridcell">lala</td>
          <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsa</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you are expecting maximum content in comment column you can just assign a class in which you can give a width to it

Answer (score 0):

`javascript`, [`dispay:grid/contents`](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/abboqbR) could be options, but a wrapper and `position:sticky` could be  a compromise to avoid breaking the table-layout  , here is below a demo of the idea

```css
.modal {
  height: 300px;
  border:solid;
}

.first {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

table.list {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 40px;
}

thead tr {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

tr {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

td {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background-color: red;
}

tr:hover td {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="first">
    <table class="list" role="grid">
      <thead>
        <tr role="row">
          <th role="columnheader">Date</th>
          <th role="columnheader">Action</th>
          <th role="columnheader">Comment</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 24</td>
          <td role="gridcell">somoene</td>
          <td role="gridcell">ddddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 23</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">ddddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 22</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">dd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 21</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">asd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 20</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadasdsa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 14</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsadsadsa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 24</td>
          <td role="gridcell">somoene</td>
          <td role="gridcell">ddddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 23</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">ddddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 22</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">dd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 21</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">asd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 20</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadasdsa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 14</td>
          <td role="gridcell">someone</td>
          <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsadsadsa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
          <td role="gridcell">Mar 7</td>
          <td role="gridcell">lala</td>
          <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsa</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```